# how curdate function could return date in mm/dd/yyyy format php

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, date-format

I need to select current date from database in mm/dd/yyyy format..But php curdate() function returns date format in yyyy-mm-dd as default..How could I resolve this issue.?

My model function is:

```
public function get_cat($category)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        if($category!='')
        {
            $this->db->like('Category',$category,'both');
            $this->db->from('tbl_job');
            $this->db->where('Expiry_date >=','DATE(CURDATE())',FALSE);
            $result = $this->db->get();
        }
        return $result->result();
    }
```

Comment: I'm using varchar type in my db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to format the date

```
DATE_FORMAT(curdate(), '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Str_to_date`

```
Str_to_date(Expiry_date,'%m/%d/%Y')
```

Try this code :-

```
$this->db->where('Str_to_date(Expiry_date,'%m/%d/%Y') >=','DATE(CURDATE())',FALSE);
```